# How to set Currency Format in braintree transaction sale

Tags: php, transactions, braintree

I create a APP in which i use Braintree Payment Gateway. In my application i make options to set different currency, am just know that how to set currency when i set sale transaction param.

here is my code

```
$result = Braintree\Transaction::sale([
                    'amount' => '50.00',
                    'creditCard' => array(
                     'cardholderName' => 'Test Name',
                     'number' => '4000111111111511',
                     'expirationDate' => '12/2018',
                     'cvv' => '123',
                    ),
                    'options' => [ 'submitForSettlement' => true]
              ]);
```

All of my transaction made in US Dollar, but i want to make transaction in different currencies.

Please someone give me the solution.
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

You will need to [set up a different merchant account](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/currencies#multi-currency-setups) for each currency you would like to process. Then, when processing a transaction for a specific currency, you can pass in the [merchant account id to the transaction sale method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php#merchant_account_id).

In addition, to keep your PCI compliance burden low, you will want to [pass a nonce to your server](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2#send-payment-method-nonce-to-server) in place of the credit card details.

```
$merchantAccountId = someFunctionToLookupCorrectMerchantIdBasedOnCurrency();

$result = Braintree\Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => '100.00',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => nonceFromTheClient,
    'merchantAccountId' => $merchantAccountId,
    'options' => [
        'submitForSettlement' => True
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks BladeBarringer

Comment: Thanks, for me it's works only after specifying `merchantAccountId` here: `$gateway->clientToken()->generate(['merchantAccountId' => 'my_merchant_account_id']);`